# Creating directory on a remote computer windows 8

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8

I have the following code, which worked fine when I tried to connect to my Virtual Machine hosting Windows 7:

```
string outputPath = @"\\" + sHost + "\\C$" + batchRunPath + jobName;
if (Directory.Exists(outputPath))
{
      listOfMessages.Items.Add("Job named " + jobName + " already exists.");
}
else
      Directory.CreateDirectory(outputPath);
```

My host computer is going to be Windows 8, and I'm trying to run the same piece of code.

This time, I get the following IO error:

> Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

I guess I must add the credentials to the connection string, the question is how...

Any ideas?

Comment: use nev view to establish a connection and then see what happens

Comment: you may need to `impersonate` a user account on the windows 8 machine. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka.aspx

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance, but what's nev view?

Comment: Admin shares (c$ etc) are disabled by default on Win8. You should set up a normal share and use that.

Comment: Well, I did set up a full control share, but I still get the same error.

Comment: are you on a Domain or in a Homegroup?

Comment: File Permissions?( _NOT_ share permissions)

Comment: Can you create this same directory manually from a command prompt?

Comment: Ok, added full control to all users...now I get: `Access to the path '\\10.0.0.160\C$\BatchRun\job' is denied.`... Pete - how can I do it from command prompt?

Comment: You cant use ADMIN shares(C$,D$ etc) on Windows8 create 'standard' share.

Comment: Ok, I changed it to `C` and shared `C:\` as `C` on my win8 machine...still nothing.

Comment: Are you using a NAT network adapter or a Bridged connection to your network? Change it to Bridge. IPConfig /renew, then IPConfig /registerDNS should work then...

Comment: Even the C$ share should then work

Comment: Thanks guys, it works now...I've made many things, but I think in the end it was probably a sharing problem.